# É possível consultar por região/país no analytics?

Tags: suporte

Ao chegar aos [25.000 pontos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) é possível ter acesso ao analytics do site https://pt.stackoverflow.com/site-analytics/traffic-sources

Tem duas abas, `histórico` e `fontes de tráfego`, todavia a aba de fontes apresenta apenas a origem, mas ele só apresenta **Sites de Origem** e **Sites de busca**.

Gostaria de saber se é possível exibir/filtrar por região (país e estado).

Comment: Nem nos analytics de moderadores tem por região :(

Comment: O legal é que essa postagem se destina a basicamente 11 pessoas. :P

Comment: @GuilhermeLautert privilégios, logo alcançará :D

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento não tem tanta pergunta de REGEX assim hehe

Comment: @GuilhermeLautert só tem as de `.htaccess`, mas são todas repetidas que uma resposta sua já responde metade. Por falar nisso eu ia fazer uma pergunta de regex, mas aquela sua resposta e a do Sérgio resolveram minha duvida XD ... foram muito boas

Comment: @GuilhermeLautert tem 11 acima de 25k? Pensei que era ainda menos hehe